# Read selected value of select box and pass it to jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I'm pretty new to JSP, HTML, ... and have a question:

I have a JSP and I'm trying to read a selected value from a HTML select box, e.g. with JavaScript:

```
<form name="ListForm" action=""> 
<select name="country" size="6">
<%
    String[] testArray = {"Germany", "Russia", "China", "Iran", "USA", "Israel"};
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
%>
        <option value=<%=testArray[i]%>>
        <%= testArray[i] %> 
        </option>
<%
    }
%>
</select> 
</form>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSelectedValue() {
        var e = document.getElementById("country");
        return e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to pass this String to another JSP:

```
<% 
    String testVar = request.getParameter("country");
    session.setAttribute("varName", testVar); 
%>
```

But that doesn't work. Do you have a idea why?

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. The code doesn't seem to be complete either. You're nowhere showing how you're submitting the form. So I would assume that the problem is simply that you didn't submit the form at all. Further, that JavaScript code is not only broken (`id` and `name` are not the same), but it seems pretty useless, I would have wondered why it is there. Just remove that JS code and add a `<input type="submit">` to the `<form>` and press it. Or isn't that what you're asking?

Comment: When I try to read the saved parameter in the next jsp, I get "null" instead of the selected value.
I don't know if I submit the form, but I get to the next jsp with:
    <p><a href="<%= readyURL %>">Next &rarr;</a></p>
Should I insert kind of a submit-statement?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue might be that your select menu has the name `country` but not the id `country`. Therefore you won't geht the select menu with `document.getElementById("country");`

You can fix this by adding an id to your `<select>` tag:

```
<select id="country" name="country" size="6">
```

However you don't need javascript to send the selected value to the server.

You should add a submit button to your form:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

And don't forget to configure the `action` in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form name="ListForm" action="[server url]">
```

Comment: That's true, thank you. But it didn't fix the problem. Still, I get "null" instead of the selected value.